# Wordpress Menu Navigation links not working

Tags: menus, themes, navigation

Navigation Menu links not working, but the bootstrap CSS is working. Can anyone help me in getting the links working? Thank you[image]

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">            
      <?php
      wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'before' => '<class="nav-item active">',      
        'menu_class' =>'navbar-nav mr-auto',
        'link_before' =>'<a class="nav-link" href="#">',      
        'link_after' =>'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>', 
        'container' => false, 
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
      ));
      ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things I noticed.

You don't want to include the `<a>` inside of `link_before` or `link_after`, you will get 2 links if you do that.  You also don't need the `<ul>`. Instead I think you want something like this...

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'before' => '<class="nav-item active">',      
        'menu_class' =>'navbar-nav mr-auto',
        'link_before' =>'<span class="nav-link">',      
        'link_after' =>'</span>', 
        'container' => false, 
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
    ));
?>
```

You should read more about [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're using dead link (#) in *link_before*. You can test removing "#" from *link_before*

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">            
          <?php
          wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'headerMenuLocation',
            'before' => '<class="nav-item active">',      
            'menu_class' =>'navbar-nav mr-auto',
            // 'link_before' =>'<a class="nav-link" href="#">',
                                  //problem is here {href="#"}     
            // 'link_after' =>'<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>', 
            'container' => false, 
            'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
          ));
          ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you its working..